# The reason why the function to query owner of NFTs is not included in ERC1155 unlike ERC721

Tags: erc-1155

I'd like to know the reason why the function to query the owner of NFTs is not offered in ERC1155 unlike ERC721.
It seems possible to query the owner of token whether it is NFT or FT. What's the problem with this function?

Answer (score 1):

Because the ERC1155 is a semi-fungible token standard. Which means that a potentially very big amount of tokens can be living on the blockchain for a given ID, and plenty of accounts could own one single copy of this token in their wallet.
That would lead to a big iteration to return an array of owner addresses, this is gas costly and probably not what we want in an OZ standard.